# Servo motor rotating without a PWM

Tags: servo

I have seen a circuit that lets a 1171 mg servo servo rotates freely a 360 degree without providing it a PWM signal; however, a DC voltage only is that possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Remove all the electronics in the servo and only leave the gears and motor. Then it just becomes a regular motor with a gearbox.

Comment: References 2, 3 of the following might help: 
(1) SG 5010 Servo 360 degree modification problem - RpiSE Q&A 2019apr28
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97999/sg-5010-servo-360-degree-modification-not-working.